# There's no Direct3D in my regedit. What should i do?

Tags: directx, regedit, d3dx

[image]

as you can see, there's no Direct3D file in regedit.
I need to find memory leaks in my code.
i already used _CrtSetBreakAlloc to clear all memory leaks!

> D3DX: MEMORY LEAKS DETECTED: 60 allocations unfreed (4603 bytes)
> D3DX: Set HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\D3DXBreakOnAllocId=0x736 to debug

this is the message i got in visual studio when i debug my D3DX.

1. How can i find my Direct3D file in my regedit?
2. if isn't possible, is there any other way to use D3DXBreakOnAllocId?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which version of Windows you are using, but it is important to note that the DirectX Developer Runtime for DirectX 9 (i.e. Direct3D's debug device) is *not supported* on Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10.

You can still manually create that specific registry key that is used by the debug version of the legacy D3DX9 utility library library.

- Select HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft in the tree view
- Select Edit \ New \ Key...
- Set the name to "Direct3D"
- Select Edit \ New \ DWORD (32-bit) Value...
- Set the name to "D3DXBreakOnAllocId"
- Set the value to your target like "736" (with the Hexadecimal radio button selected)

> Be aware that the DirectX SDK, Direct3D 9, the D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11 libraries, and the "DirectX End-User Runtime" (i.e. DXSETUP.EXE/DXWEBSETUP.EXE/DirectSetup API) are all [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-). See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2021 Edition)?](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/).